# How can I stop a postgres table from having duplicate record and instead writing the duplicate records in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-9.1

How can I stop a Postgres table from having duplicate record and instead writing the duplicate records in another table. I want to copy data from “table1” to “table2” and if there is any duplicate data in “table1” then it should be copied to “duplicates” instead of “table2”.

The problem is:

1. Creating a *unique key* on `table2` stops the data insertion with error

> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> ```

unlike in MySQL where an IGNORE command can be used.

1. Creating a rule on `table2` does not help for a check per ROW basis.

   ```
   CREATE  RULE "copy_dup" AS ON INSERT TO "table2"
   WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE (field1, field2, field3) =
   (NEW.field1, NEW.field2, NEW.field3))
   DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO duplicates 
   (field1, field2, field3)  
   VALUES
   (NEW.field1, NEW.field2, NEW.field3);

   INSERT INTO "table2"
   (field1, field2, field3)   
   SELECT 
   field1, field2, field3 FROM table1;
   ```
2. Creating a *trigger* is giving syntax error at when:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION data_insert_table2()
     RETURNS void AS
   $$
   BEGIN

   INSERT INTO table2(field1, field2, field3)
   SELECT field1, field2, field3
   FROM table1;

   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

   CREATE TRIGGER ignore_dup
   BEFORE INSERT ON table2
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE  data_insert_table2();
   ```

   > ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHEN"

Does trigger not support WHEN clause ?

I am not very intimate with Postgres. Can anyone help?

Both `table1` and `table2` have primary key on their `serial_id` which is not being copied from one table to another.

I am not sure whether this function works as trigger fails at `WHEN`.

Comment: Your trigger function definition for `data_insert_table2()` is missing.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That doesn't make a lot of odds if it's only getting as far as the `WHEN` and then bombing out with a syntax error surely?

Comment: Does this operation need to be repeatable on-demand in some way? Because if not, you could just craft a pair of `SELECT` queries that selected a) the first of each set of duplicates (including rows which are not duplicated), and b) all but the first of each set of duplicates. (Beware of [asking for help with a possibly non-optimal solution rather than the original problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: @IMSoP: For a complete answer I need these details. The error at hand is trivial (using `OLD` in an `INSERT` trigger) ...

Comment: Also, is there a primary key in `table1`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter My point was that I think the `TRIGGER ... WHEN` approach is a dead end anyway, so it's not worth knowing details of it; the top of the question explains the desired functionality, although I do suspect an X/Y Problem here.

Comment: @IMSoP: Turns out, the OP was after the trigger solution all along.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem

Your trigger fails for (at least) this reason: the [special variable **`OLD`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) is not defined for `INSERT` triggers. There is no "old" row, like in `DELETE` or `UPDATE` triggers.

#### Permanent solution with trigger

Otherwise a trigger solution should work just fine. Building on your updated question:

```
CREATE FUNCTION data_insert_table2()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
-- 
INSERT INTO dupe(field1, field2, field3)  -- insert into other table
SELECT NEW.field1, NEW.field2, NEW.field3
WHERE EXISTS (                            -- if dupe is already in table2
   SELECT 1 FROM table2
   WHERE (field1, field2, field3) = (NEW.field1, NEW.field2, NEW.field3)
   );

IF FOUND THEN        -- only if the above wrote to the dupe table ..
   RETURN NULL;      -- .. cancel original INSERT
END IF;

RETURN NEW;          -- else proceed normally

END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ignore_dup
BEFORE INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW          -- no WHEN condition!
EXECUTE PROCEDURE  data_insert_table2();
```

#### One-time operation

For a one-time operation I would go with a query using [data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), though (Postgres 9.1 or later):

```
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (field1, field2, field3)  -- fold duplicates in source
             pk_col, field1, field2, field3
      FROM   table1
      ORDER  BY field1, field2, field3, pk_col     -- take "first" row per set
      ) t
   LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 USING (field1, field2, field3)
   WHERE  t2.field1 IS NULL                        -- except rows in table2
   )
, ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3) 
   SELECT field1, field2, field3
   FROM   sel
   )
INSERT INTO dupes (field1, field2, field3) 
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3
FROM   table1 t
LEFT   JOIN sel USING (pk_col)
WHERE  sel.pk_col IS NULL;
```

Combine that with a `UNIQUE` constraint on `table2` to make sure your requirements are met.

Note that two columns holding NULL ate not considered the same. If you disagree with this standard SQL definition, you have to define all columns `NOT NULL` to make this work.

This operation is prone to race conditions. If multiple clients might be running this  concurrently, you'd need exclusive locks. But it looks like a single-user job.

Comment: Permanent solution with trigger was giving an error while creating function. "ERROR: NEW used in query that is not in a rule". I could get rid of this error by replacing "RETURNS void AS " -> "RETURNS TRIGGER AS". Otherwise this query is perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @nitxx: Of course, fixed. A trigger needs `RETURNS trigger`. Slipped my attention when copying your original.